# Running XHTML and HTML on the same page?

Tags: html, jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml

Is it possible to run html and xhtml on the same page? I am using jsf and need to integrate it in a template.

Comment: If you mean just using HTML plain tags in XHTML views, yes, it is possible.

Comment: I don't see the problem; valid XHTML is also valid HTML in most cases (there are exceptions, like the contents of <script> elements etc), so can you give an example of something that causes problems?

Answer (score -1):

if you really need to give them the .html extension, then you'd need to change the default suffix to .html as well. Add the following entry to web.xml to achieve that:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.html</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Hello yashar ,  its not about the suffix . I generated the pagzs using reverse method from databse even for the crud . And i have a template in html . I want to integrate the result on the template u see ?